# Does Qt4 implement drag and drop with window icons?

Tags: macos, user-interface, drag-and-drop, qt4, pyqt4

Several windows in OS X have drag-and-droppable window icons (e.g. Terminal, Keynote, Finder). Can Qt4 window icons be set up for drag and drop? I can't figure out whether clicking on the window icon triggers any event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this feature is specific to only one platform it may not directly available in Qt. Probably you will have to use Cocoa API to handle such events. You can get native window handle:

> WId QWidget::winId () const Returns the window system identifier of
>   the widget.
>
> Portable in principle, but if you use it you are probably about to do
>   something non-portable. Be careful.
>
> If a widget is non-native (alien) and winId() is invoked on it, that
>   widget will be provided a native handle.
>
> On Mac OS X, the type returned depends on which framework Qt was
>   linked against. If Qt is using Carbon, the {WId} is actually an
>   HIViewRef. If Qt is using Cocoa, {WId} is a pointer to an NSView.

With such handle you probably will be able to handle "window icon drag" with native (not portable!) Mac OS X code